# Attaching all documents in a drive folder then send it as an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've spent several days searching this and I find answers pretty close to what I'm looking for but not exactly it. I'm new to coding and trying to learn based on need + researching on the side.

Open Google sheet, inside would have a button that runs this script (I can do this now).
This sheet is used repeatedly and can be saved in different folders. It's used as a request form, in the same folder are additional documentations for the request.

I want the script to send the Active Sheet as well as 'All' other files in the same folder as an email attachment (could possibly use a link but rather the entire file).
It will then be sent to the recipients (that part of the code is not listed below)

Below is what I have so far: (This lists all files in the active folder and puts it in the Sheet, this is not necessary if there is another way). I then need it to attach each file-ID as an attachment. The folder structure is something like

Also, I'm still trying to understand setting the MIME, is there a way that can capture several different file types? PDF, JPG and XLSX...?

root\Person_Name\UniqueFolderName\

```
function listFiles() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
var folderID = DriveApp.getFolderById(ssID).getParents();
var foldernewID = folderID.next().getId(); 
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(foldernewID).getFiles();
var list = [];

list.push(['Name', 'ID', 'Size']);

while (files.hasNext()){
file = files.next();
var row = [];
row.push(file.getName(),file.getId(),file.getSize())
list.push(row);
}

ss.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list);
Logger.log(list);
}
```

Also, the additional file types in the folder are .xlsx and .pdf

Any help would be greatly appreciated or pointing me in the right direction, I've tried several sites and most show attaching 1-2 files using their ID built in the script, my IDs will always be new and there could be more than 2-3+ so need a loop or something.

Thank you

Comment: Try using [`sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options) method in [Class GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app). You can add `attachments`, an advanced parameter which you can use for an array of files with the email. However, note that `.xlsx` file types are currently not supported.

Comment: See this [related SO post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/send-an-email-with-attachment-using-google-apps-script) for additional insights.